# Theoretical question about elevators

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

**Question**

Imagine we put a bascule/weighing machine in an elevator, and that elevator starts to acelerate downwards with a certain aceleration that we don't know of. Is it true that the bascule will always register less than if the bascule was in stationary position, or more, or more than if it was accelerating upwards, or is there not enough information to answer this?

**Thoughts/ideas**

I'm thinking towards less than when the elevator is in stationary position since $N=m(g−a)$ if it is accelerating downwards.

Comment: What is, "bascule?" Is it [this?](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:200_-_gram_balance_scales.jpg) or is it [this?](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Weighing_balance,_MNIT.jpg) One _compares_ the force of gravity/acceleration on an unknown mass vs. the same acceleration/gravity acting on one or more known masses. The other _measures_ the force of gravity/acceleration acting on an unknown mass. One is _indifferent_ to the ambient gravity/acceleration, the other must be _calibrated_ according to the strength of the ambient acceleration/gravity in the place where it will be used.

Comment: Sorry yes, the second one, the weighing machine/balance

Comment: Try imagining what will happen when the elevator is in free fall (accelerating with g).

Comment: The second one—the modern, electronic laboratory balance—measures the force acting downward on its pan. The force is presumed to be due to gravity acting on the unknown sample, and the instrument is calibrated to accurately report the number of grams that would experience that force _in the place where the instrument is installed._ Move it to a different location (especially to a different elevation) and a high precision weighing machine will need to be re-calibrated before it gives accurate results.

Comment: @SolomonSlow what does that have to do with my question?

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist if it falls at in a free fall the bascule would measure 0, since g-a=0. But I'm still confused

Comment: @Acedium20 Now you can generalize this to the case where acceleration can be anything, Find the forces acting on the mass and elevator, and remember that the weight you'll be measuring would be the normal force between mass and elevator.

Comment: So it is then true that the weight measured will be always higher than those at rest?

Comment: Re, "what does that have to do with my question?" It's because the behavior of the pan balance in the elevator will be distinctly different from the behavior of the electronic "balance." The electronic one isn't really a balance at all: It is a _scale._ It measures _force._ The pan balance compares _masses._

Comment: @Acedium20 no, it depends on the direction of acceleration, as you saw yourself for the case when g=a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let a mass $m$ be on the scale. In the non-inertial reference frame moving with the elevator, there is a fictitious force on $m$ upwards equal to $ma$ where $a$ is the downward acceleration of the elevator.  The total force on $m$ downwards is $m(g - a)$.  The total force on $m$ upwards is $m(g - a)$ to keep $m$ at rest in the frame of the elevator. This upwards force is on $m$ from the scale, and there is an equal and opposite force on the scale from $m$ and this is the weight.  The weight is $m(g - a)$ which is less than the weight $mg$ for the elevator at rest.  For free fall of the elevator, $a = g$; the mass is weightless.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is essentially the same as [John Darby's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/96891/john-darby) but with the use of the inertial frame.

Let us situate ourselves outside the elevator of mass $M$ and let the elevator have some acceleration $\vec a$. This is a vector quantity and can point in any direction, that is elevator can go up as well down. The elevator also has a mass $m$ in it.

The forces of the elevator are
$$F_{elevator}=M\vec g+\vec N=M\vec a$$

Here $\vec N$ is the normal force between mass and elevator

For the mass our equation are
$$F_{mass}=m\vec g-\vec N=m\vec a$$

Here the assumption has been made that both elevator and mass are moving with the same acceleration, if that's not the case then either mass tears the elevator and leaves it or moves with acceleration $\vec g$, in both cases $\vec N=0$.

There is also a case when the acceleration of the elevator is greater than that of the mass but at this point, mass is within the walls of the elevator, that is it hasn't yet touched the elevator, however for that case we need to know the force that s cases the acceleration of elevator at the first place.